# Python using the ctypes library with math.h but the answer is always 0

Tags: python, c

I want to use cytypes to load a C shared library (lib*.so),but I noticed once I use math.h in the C file,I can't load it correctly. The answer is always 0. Here is my source code in my shared library:

```
#include <math.h>

double mycos(double num){
   return cos(num);
}
```

and I just build it like this:

```
 gcc -shared -o libtest.so cos.o
```

Here is my C code to load it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern double mycos(double num);

int main(){
    printf("%lf",mycos(30));
    return 0;
}
```

After add my libtest.so to /etc/ld.so.conf , I run my code:

```
gcc test.c libtest.so -lm
./a.out
```

the answer is 0.154251, which is a correct answer.

However, when I run it in Python console:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mylib = CDLL('/home/ubuntu/test/libtest.so')
>>> y=mylib.mycos(30)
>>> y
0
```

The answer is 0. I also test other shared library which doesn't use math.h, the answer is correct. How does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to specify the [argument types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) and [return type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types) first: ctypes doesn't know that your function expects the argument as a double and will return a double. Try:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mylib = CDLL('/home/ubuntu/test/libtest.so')
>>> mylib.mycos.argtypes = [c_double]
>>> mylib.mycos.restype = c_double
>>> y=mylib.mycos(30)
>>> y
```

Without these it won't be passing the 30 in correctly or interpreting the response correctly. (I'd guess the argument is effectively 0, since the 30 will end up somewhere in the mantissa of the double, and that the result of cos(0)=1 has four least-significant bytes of 0 which Python is reading back as a zero int result.)